# Throwing up a Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CC_Update()

    Dim DateR As Range
    Dim Update_till As Date
    
    Dim Linked_Users_CC As Range
    Dim Applications_CC As Range
    Dim New_Provisioned_CC As Range
    Dim Total_Accounts_Act_CC As Range
    Dim total_Spend_CC As Range
    Dim total_Transactions_CC As Range
    Dim App_To_Provisioned_CC As Range
    
    ' Set the ranges for the data
    Set DateR = Range("B5:B32")
    Update_till = Range("'Audit'!C1")
    Set Linked_Users_CC = Range("D2:D31")
    Set Applications_CC = Range("H2:H31")
    Set New_Provisioned_CC = Range("L2:L31")
    Set Total_Accounts_Act_CC = Range("P2:P31")
    Set total_Spend_CC = Range("U2:U31")
    Set total_Transactions_CC = Range("V2:V31")
     
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To DateR.Rows.Count
        If DateR.Cells(i, 1).Value <= Update_till Then
            Linked_Users_CC.Cells(i, 1).formula = "='Users Forecast'!R[0]C9"
            Applications_CC.Cells(i, 1).formula = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,applications!C2:C3,2,FALSE))"
            New_Provisioned_CC.Cells(i, 1).formula = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,new_accounts_provisioned!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
            Total_Accounts_Act_CC.Cells(i, 1).formula = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,total_cc_accounts!C1:C2,2,FALSE),P21)"
            total_Spend_CC.Cells(i, 1).formula = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,total_transactions_and_spend!C1:C3,2,FALSE)"
            total_Transactions_CC.Cells(i, 1).formula = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,total_transactions_and_spend!C1:C3,3,FALSE)"

            
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I am trying to build a macro that fills out cells based on dates with VLOOKUP formulas but it keeps throwing up and error

Comment: change the `.Formula` to `.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: Still gives me the same error

Comment: Which line throws the error

Comment: It doesnt Show the line just the Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: You cant mix A1 and R1C1

Comment: You are missing `'` around your sheet names.

Comment: also you seem to have something extra n this formula: `"=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,total_cc_accounts!C1:C2,2,FALSE),P21)"`  the `,P21)` probably should be removed.

Comment: Yeah Tim, you are correct but that still doesn solve the issue for some reason. Scott i removed that P21 and added the ' but still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you enter those same formulas manually?

Comment: Yeah they work when just used as simple vlookup formulas (Without the R1C1 through)

Comment: Which specific formula(s) have an error?

Comment: when it errors you should be given the option of debug.  Which will take you to the code and highlight the line.

Comment: and can you post the new code with the above suggestions?

Comment: `DateR` is rows 5:32 but other ranges are 2:31 ?  Should they be consistent?

Comment: You also have an extra `)` at the end of `"=VLOOKUP(R[0]C2,applications!C2:C3,2,FALSE))"`

Comment: I got it! it was the Update_till = Range("'Audit'!C1") line

Answer (score 0):

Update_till = Range("'Audit'!C1")  is incorrect since its linked to an outside sheet refreance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).